# Python 3.4.2 tkinter troubleshooting

Tags: tkinter, installation, python-3.4

I'm having some trouble getting tkinter to work in my scripts.

I'm writing code on a Fedora 22 machine, it had by default python 2.7 and python 3.4 installed and everywhere I read that tkinter is default with python installs.

Where I try to make sure it works using the python3 interpreter

```
import tkinter
```

I get th following error

```
ImportError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

Then if I try to install it

```
sudo pip install python3-tk
```

I get the following error

```
No matching distribution found for python3-tk
```

I'm not sure where to go next with this

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems there indeed was no tkinter default install but to install it I needed an extra step

```
sudo dnf builddep python3
```

then I could install using

```
sudo dnf install python3-tkinter
```